# Django : DiscoverRunner overriding raise error

Tags: python, django, testing, overriding, manage.py

I'm currently trying to define an other test_runner. 
To do so, i changed my `settings.py` :

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'test_runner.MezzoTestsRunner'
```

Here is my `MezzoTestsRunner` class :

```
class MezzoTestsRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MezzoTestsRunner,self).__init__(keepdb=True)
```

Then I used command : `python manage.py test`

```
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 89, in handle
    test_runner = TestRunner(**options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbosity'
```

I'm really suprised to have this result.. Does someone have already had the same ?

Thank you :)

PS : I'm using django 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really solved my problem, but i can escape the problem.
I wasn't able to change `keepdb` in `__init__()`, so i changed it in `run_tests()` method :

```
class MezzoTestsRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        self.keepdb=True
        super(MezzoTestsRunner,self).run_tests(test_labels,extra_tests, **kwargs)
```